# AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'db'

Tags: python, database, flask, request, flask-sqlalchemy

I do not really understand what's the problem with it? I would like to use Flask's before and after request functions, otherwise my sessions are not closed and then I get time outs. These are my app's settings please help me to understand why I get "AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'db'":

```
app = Flask(__name__)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

app.secret_key = 'somekey'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/database'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from models import *

login_manager.login_message = 'Please login first.'
login_manager.login_view = 'authenticate'

#################################
#################################

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    """user_loader - A decorator to mark the function responsible for loading a user from whatever data source we use."""
    return User.query.filter(User.id == int(user_id)).first()


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db.connect()
    g.user = current_user

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Close the database connection after each request"""
    g.db.close()
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to combine the SQLite example from the Flask docs with the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension, but the two are not related.  There is no `g.db`, you interact with the database with the `db` object.

Remove the `before_request` and `after_request` functions.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. How to close sessions after each request?